# Getting NullReferenceException when calling expression with multiple parameters in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I am trying to construct function that accepts more that one parameter. Lambda function accepting one parameter works fine. Here is the code.

```
var value = 22.55;
var method = typeof(TextWriter).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { value.GetType() });
ParameterExpression inputParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TextWriter));
var block = Expression.Block(
    inputParameter,
    Expression.Call(inputParameter, method, Expression.Constant(value)));
var function = Expression.Lambda<Action<TextWriter>>(block, inputParameter).Compile();
function(Console.Out);
```

However when I add one more parameter that I do not even use then function throws null reference exception. I must be missing something but have no idea what. Here is the code that does not work:

```
var value = 22.55;
var method = typeof(TextWriter).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { value.GetType() });
ParameterExpression inputParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TextWriter));
// Additional parameter here
ParameterExpression inputParameter2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double));
var block = Expression.Block(
    // Function block accepts two parameters
    new List<ParameterExpression>() { inputParameter, inputParameter2 },
    Expression.Call(inputParameter, method, Expression.Constant(value)));

var function = Expression.Lambda<Action<TextWriter, double>>(block, inputParameter, inputParameter2).Compile();
// ....aaand null exception here. Why?
function(Console.Out, value);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your comment, you're misunderstanding what you're passing to `Block`. The `variables` argument of Block is to define local variables, rather than parameters.

```
var block = Expression.Block(
    // Function block accepts two parameters
    new List<ParameterExpression>() { inputParameter, inputParameter2 },
    Expression.Call(inputParameter, method, Expression.Constant(value)));
```

Should be simply

```
var block = Expression.Block(Expression.Call(inputParameter, method, Expression.Constant(value)));
```

What you're currently doing is equivelant to:

```
void function(TextWriter tw, double d) {
    TextWriter tw = default(TextWriter);
    double d = default(double);

    tw.WriteLine(22.55);    
}
```

While you *actually* just want:

```
void function(TextWriter tw, double d) {
    tw.WriteLine(22.55);    
}
```

Also, you're not actually using your second parameter. The complete working code is:

```
var method = typeof(TextWriter).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(double) });
ParameterExpression inputParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TextWriter));
ParameterExpression inputParameter2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double));
var block = Expression.Block(Expression.Call(inputParameter, method, inputParameter2));
var function = Expression.Lambda<Action<TextWriter, double>>(block, inputParameter, inputParameter2).Compile();
function(Console.Out, 35.5);
```

Your first code worked because you used a different overload of block. Instead of declaring a local variable for `inputParameter`, you passed it as an expression itself. So, the code looked like this:

```
void function(TextWriter tw, double d) {
    tw; //Illegal for the C# compiler, but not illegal as an expression. This will do nothing.
    tw.WriteLine(22.55);    
}
```

Comment: I thought the first parameter of Expression.Block declared function parameters. I was misled by names of variables in the sample code I was looking at. Now everything looks great.